# List of Titles and how to unlock them

Tags: street-fighter-x-tekken

In game you have numerous ways to unlock titles for showing off during online play. I was wondering if anyone has stumbled upon a list of said titles and how to unlock them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there's a list of what is, as far as I know, all the titles [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/999532-street-fighter-x-tekken/62156430). I haven't found anything to tell you how to get them, though. I'll copy the list in here in case the link goes dead, and so it's better formatted. It's a very long list. If anyone knows how to get any of these, feel free to edit it in, formatted:

- Title - method of acquirement

And here's the list:

White = finishing most of the trials

Blue = finishing all the trials

Red = beat arcade mode on medium (or lower I think)

Gold = beat arcade mode on hardest

**Kazuya**

- Heartless
- Devil In The Dark
- Devil's Power
- Original Hero
- Endless Charisma
- Big Bad Guy
- Wind God Fist B
- If I Was King... B

**Nina**

- ## 1 Assassin
- Cool Beautiful
- Work Comes First
- 20 Year Old Body
- Dangerous Curves
- Hate My Sister
- Cool Killer B
- High Battle Sense B
- From the Dark R
- Certain Kill G

**Asuka**

- Fight Mediator
- Kazama Style
- Osaka School Gal
- Gonna Smack Ya!
- What The Heck!?
- Never Gonna Lose!
- All For The Laughs B
- Girl Power B

**Lili**

- Tomboy
- Hasty Daredevil
- Total Beatdown!
- Don't Tell My Father
- Fighting Celebrity
- Team Time (music note)
- Doing As I Please B
- Million Dollar Gal B

**Heihachi**

- The World Is Mine
- Tekken Lord
- Mishima Karate Style
- Miraculous Old Man
- Bursting With Power
- Unstoppable Storm
- Nice Hairstyle B
- Absolute Ruler B

**Kuma**

- Special Move = Farts
- Thinking Of Panda
- The Bear
- No Ordinary Bear
- TV Kid
- Kuma Shin Ken Style
- Looking For Mishimas B
- Wild and Cranky B

**Paul**

- ## 1 In The Universe
- Furious Fighter
- Undying Phoenix
- Crushing Fist
- Wild Old Man
- Mister Comical
- In Debt B
- Spirit Of A Man B

**Law**

- Marshall China
- Cooking Dragon
- I Just Needed Cash
- Spicy Cooking
- The Poor Man
- Got A Family
- Down But Not Out B
- Secret Recipe B

**King**

- Wild Masked Wrestler
- The Successor
- Ring Hunter
- Jaguar Mask
- Feeling Excited
- Muscle Buster!
- Babyface B
- Technician B

**Marduk**

- Roaring Beast
- Vale Tudo Fighter
- Violent Warrior
- Power Puncher
- Daunting Adversary
- Caged Animal
- Love My Muscles B
- Outta Control B

**Hwoarang**

- For master Baek
- I want Power!
- Blood Talon
- Reckless Rascal
- Feet BeforeFists
- Storm & Stress
- Need To Fight Him B
- Surprsingly Serious B

**Steve**

- Cool Boxer
- Can Kick Too
- Quick Combos
- Sucker Knuckle
- Studly Man
- Sharp Edge
- Hellfire! B
- Unlucky Numbers B
- No Match Fixing! R
- World Champ G

**Julia**

- Earth's Soldier
- Gal With Glasses
- Intelligent Lady
- Nature Is My Friend
- Ever Green
- Cool & Cute
- Fight At Full Power B
- $10,000 Smile B

**Bob**

- The Perfect Body
- My Body's A weapon
- Weight Is Power
- Nice Bounty hunter
- Super heavyweight
- Terrfying Blubber
- Gun Speed Star B
- Six Meals A Day B

**Yoshimitsu**

- Manji Clan Leader
- Cursed Sword
- Seppuku!!
- Unidentifiable
- Unique Ninja
- Demon Cutter
- A Flash TO Cut Evil B
- Escaping Darkness B
- Likeable Dude R
- Idiom Dictionary G

**Raven**

- Nice Black Suit
- Stylish Ninja
- Broody Man
- Evening Bird
- Agent With Shades
- Gets The Job Done
- Hard Worker B
- Cross Scar Face B

**Xiayou**

- Devoted To Jin
- Panda's My Pet
- All For Love!
- Tons Of Courage!
- Soaring Love
- So Shoe Me
- Lovely Pigtails! B
- To Protect My Love B

**Jin**

- Farewell To my Past
- Mishima Zaibatsu #1
- Fateful Flash
- I Love My Forests
- A World In Chaos
- Dark Hero
- Escaping The Devil B
- Destroy The Mishimas B

**Ogre**

- From Outer Space
- Fighting God
- The Green Giant
- Ancient Warrior
- The Herald's Fist
- Nice Ponytail
- Not A Plant B
- Spirit Eater B
- I hear A Voice R
- Lives In A Pyramid G

### ***Capcom Side:***

**Poison**

- Pink Lady
- Able-Bodied Manager
- In Full Bloom
- Wanna Spank Me?
- Thee Queen?
- Strong Minded
- Heart-Warming Lass B
- Sexy Cool B

**Vega**

- Noble Masked Man
- Airborne Assassin
- Hyouuu!
- Stained With Red!
- Death Via Claw
- Deadly Serpent
- Spanish Ninja B
- Sadist B
- Searching For Beauty R
- Intelligent Madman G

**Ryu**

- True Martial Artist
- One With Nature
- Fist Of Wind
- Love My Beans
- Eternal Challenger
- Battler
- Karate Fighter B
- Metsu! Hadoken! B

**Ken**

- Come On!
- Crimson Fighter
- Fighting Dad
- Do It With Style!
- Dragon Dancer
- Nice Guy
- Shoryureppa B
- Eternal Rival B

**Chun**

- Sorry!
- Fancy Footwork
- Original Heroine
- Interpol Officer
- Lightning Legs
- Love My Sweets
- Dancing All Over You B
- The Complete Package B

**Cammy**

- Killer Bee
- Cat Girl
- Delta Red Member
- Emotionless Soldier
- Army Girl
- Battlefield Flower
- Love My Partners B
- Moody Girl B

**Guile**

- I'm Going Home
- My Hair Is Too Good
- Deal With It!
- Unmatched Accuracy
- For My Friends
- Sonic Army
- Cutting The Wind B
- My Wife's A Babe B

**Abel**

- Man With No Past
- Soft Mohican Hair
- Wanna Pet A Bear
- Seiyaaa!
- Dislikes Oysters
- Searching For Myself
- Lost Number B
- Controlling Myself B

**Gief**

- Red Cyclone
- Standing Piledriver
- Watch Your Step!
- Muscle Man
- Scars Are My Trophy!
- Slow, Hard, Strong
- Russia's Hero B
- Solid Steel Bod B

**Rufus**

- Blubbery Dancer
- Machine Gun Talker
- Legendary Biker
- Got A Pretty Gal
- Trash Talker
- Mid-Air Dancer
- Ken Maaaasters! B
- Nice Pigtail B

**Sim**

- God Of Yoga
- FIery God
- Enlightened One
- Tranquil Warrior
- Married Holy Man
- Mr. McStretchy
- I Am Not An Alien B
- Astonishing Power B

**Sagat**

- One Eyed Warrior
- Indomitable Emperor
- Tiger Tiger Tiger!
- Man Of Honor
- Quiet Power
- Swear On My Scar
- Like A King B
- Angry Fist B

**Rolento**

- Love Being Ruthless
- Win At All Costs
- Perfect Harmony
- Fanatical
- Patriot
- I Am A Soldier!
- One Man Army B
- Red Beret B

**Ibuki**

- Kunoichi In Training
- Girly Ninja Girl
- Don-chaaaan!
- Pint-sized
- Armor Is For Wimps!
- Black Ponytail
- Wanna Grow Up B
- Need A Boyfriend B

**Hugo**

- Towering Giant
- Crazy Strong
- Super Tall
- Not To Scale
- Giant Wrestler
- I'll Crush You!
- I'm Number One! B
- Not Just Big B

**Balrog**

- Mister Balrog
- Heavyweight Boxer
- Time To Get Paid!
- Not Some Lapdog
- Overwhelming Rusher
- Raging Bulldog
- My Fight Money! B
- Dirty Fighter B

**Juri**

- Love Destruction
- Alluring Wench
- Give It To Me Baby
- Creepy Spider
- Feng Shui Engine
- Smiling Darkness
- I Like My Stuff Hot B
- Spider B

**M.Bison**

- Psycho Power is #1!
- Mwuahaha!
- Immortal Dictator
- Transmogrification
- Top Baddie In Town
- Shadaloo Dictator
- Pretty Chin B
- No Time For Chumps B

**Akuma**

- Master Of The Fist
- Die 1000 Deaths!
- Destruction!
- Murderous Intent
- Ready For Death
- Eye Of A Demon
- Gokuento Resident B
- Fist To Tear Heaven B

Comment: This i think is going to be the best answer, there would be ways to make it better with a how to but i think during this early phase were still seeing this is going to be the best answer. Hopefully people will come back and edit with further info, but thank you sir or madam you have made my day. Bounty earned. :]